# Looping over grid to get label and entry text values in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a window using tkinter, this window contains a grid of Labels and Entries. In the Entries I have edited some text that I want to save back to the source.

Everything I'm reading so far says that I need to create a separate list and save each entry text variable in the list.

But isn't there a better way to get the values directly from the controls themselves? I know I can loop over `mywindow.winfo_children` or `mywindow.children`. So if I can do this, then I should be able to get the text values directly, no?

I just don't know which property to get the value from.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: _""But isn't there a better way to get the values directly from the controls themselves?_ - yes, this is all documented. Every `Entry` has a `get` method.

Comment: yeah I just posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer.

```
for child in context.grid_slaves():
    if(type(child) is label):
         print (child['text'])
    if(type(child) is entry):
         print(child.get())
```

I can also find out where I am in the grid like this: `child.grid_info()` and so I can synch back to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the answer. 
Loop through the window grid items using the grid_slaves method.

Get the row and column using the widget's grid_info method:

```
for child in window.grid_slaves():
    g_info = child.grid_info()
    if type(child) is Button:
        row = g_info['row']
        col = g_info['column']
        text = child['text']
        print(row, col, text)
```